# Play audio in slow\fast motion

Tags: objective-c, c

I am looking for my project for a way to play audio in fast\slow motion in IPhone project, it can be also in C or C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a technique called granular synthesis, there are many variations of granular synthesis some can be used to create whole new sounds, but it can also be used to change the playback speed of audio without changing the pitch. It involves chopping audio up into small blocks and the looping over each block, you can change the playback speed of each block to change pitch without changing time and you can change the rate you move between blocks to change duration without change pitch. Do a search on the internet and you will find many references to it, Apple may even have core audio API for it.